# Tags for TV series and movies

Tags: discussion, tags

Since TV is now on topic here, there's a tag for them: [tv-series](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tv-series). If that tag is going to stay around, do we need a [movies](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/movies) tag? I think so. It seems silly to have a tag for one and not for the other.

Answer (score 8):

I don't think so. If this site is to be about "TV & Movies," you cannot divvy up the content into two virtual sites as a means of ignoring one or the other. We don't have separate [science-fiction] and [fantasy] tags on every question on *that* site. Nor did we divide other sites  between [board-games]/[card-games], [electronics]/[robotics], [food]/[cooking], [quality-assurance]/[testing], etc, etc.

In the earliest days of the Cooking site, I had a few users who wanted everything tagged as [vegetarian] or [non-vegetarian]. Everything. It was based on the premise that they were only interested in that part of the site. Tagging does not work that way.

Tagging tells you what the question is about. It was never designed to drag big swaths through the middle of the site. So unless you anticipate a large number of questions explicitly about the subject of "tv-series" or explicitly about "movies", those tags will likely be filtered out (at the community or the data base level).

Tags should tell you what the question is about. Period. If you anticipate that you are going to create a "movie" and "TV" tags as a means to separate the two subjects, that simply is not going to work… nor should it.

Comment: I agree with you, but I think that this means we should burninate [tag:tv-series].

Comment: Looking at the questions the tag has been applied to, I agree. Unless I am wholly overruled on this AND there is a more comprehensive application of these tags (i.e. not piecemeal like this), they don't work as-is. I am removing them now, on that premise.

Comment: The tag was initially there to just differentiate the TV-series and anything *not* tagged with it was implied as a movie.  I suggested [in another meta answer](http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/a/252/130) that we make ones for documentaries, reality, etc to differentiate those, but I'm not 100% on that quite yet.  But, I don't think tagging somethings say similarly named items with 'movie'/'tv' is a bad thing altogether.

Comment: @TylerShads What you are suggesting is tagging questions as [tv-series] > [documentary] > [victory-at-sea] > [narration]. That's not a tagging system; it's a hierarchy. I can appreciate the story you are telling yourself; that everything can be categorized this way to make the tags meaningfully organize the entire site. But tagging wasn't designed that way. Tagging is inherently *ad hoc* and each tag should describe the content of the question; not impose some sort of pseudo-hierarchical structure to every question on the site.

Comment: I guess I see tags as more of an organizer than a descriptor.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that makes sense. They should be equal partners in this site!