# Questions grouped by movie / series

Tags: discussion, questions, search

I know we don't want [tags for movies or tv series](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240/tags-for-tv-series-and-movies). But I would be very glad if somehowe we could produce a list of unanswered questions grouped by movie (or tv series) title.

Such a grouping would make it much easier for me (and you) to pick out questions about the movies I saw and try to be helpful. I strongly doubt the effectiveness of googling & guessing on questions about movies one didn't see. The OP probably did (should have done) that already, and often better because he knows firsthand what he's looking for.

Do such grouping capabilities exist on other Stack Exchange sites? It seems a hard thing to do because tags are [not categorized](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/24721/168269) so they are not recognizable as "title" tags.

Anyone with creative ideas?

Answer (score 3):

As you saw, we passed around the idea early on because we were still considering TV on this site.  Now that it is solid, we adapted that each individual title has it's own tag so searching [title-name](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/title-name) accomplishes that goal.

As far as getting unanswered questions out, there is an [**unanswered**](https://movies.stackexchange.com/unanswered) tab, but if you do a search for

`[tag-name] answered:0`

Then you will bring up a search that has all the questions with no answers for an item with that tag.

Conversely, you can use the same query, but use

`hasaccepted:0`

Then you will bring up questions without an accepted answer.

For the time being, it seems to be the most optimal way to perform what you are asking for.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, it probably is the best we've got so far. Producing a list from which I can pick "my" movies looks like something that the Stack Exchange data model is unable to support. Which is kind of sad, because I think it would be a great help anywhere where questions on titles are involved.

Comment: Another thing I can say is to add the tags you want to follow and they will appear highlighted on the main page as well.

Comment: That's an option. Not optimal either. I still would have to pick the tags about movies myself, and keep doing it. Suppose (just suppose) I wouldn't know who Stanley Kubrick is, I might think it was a title of a movie (which is actually a good idea, come to think of it).

Comment: @GertArnold Currently, the only way to accomplish this is by what I described or if you or someone else wants to hack away at the API for a bit to come up with something as well for [stackapps](http://stackapps.com/)

Comment: Since there is no way to recognize tags as "title" tags I think that there is just no support for this. It would require a change in the tag model, which I might propose one day at meta.stackoverflow. My experience is that such change requests get voted down quickly though, so I wait until I sense there is some momentum for it.